# Degeneracy for Complex Self-Adjoint Operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose operator $T$ on a complex inner-product space is self-adjoint. Then, if
$$\dim(T-\lambda I)=2$$
And $v_1,v_2\in \ker(T-\lambda I)$ are linearly independent, then in which cases are $v_1,v_2$ complex conjugate pairs?

Comment: What do you mean by the two eigenvector s being 'complex conjugate pairs'?

Comment: i.e. the components of one vector are the complex conjugates of the components of the other vector (where these components are inner products with an orthonormal basis)

Answer (score 0):

From the physics forums (lol) Since $T$ is self-adjoint, note that if
$$ Tv=\lambda v$$
Then, the corresponding equation in the dual space holds:
$$T^*v^*=\lambda^*v^*=\lambda v^*\tag{$\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ because $T$ is self-adjoint}$$
But $T^*=T$, so $Tv^*=\lambda v^*$. So for each eigenvector of $T$, its complex conjugate is also an eigenvector of $T$ with the same eigenvalue.

Comment: The concept of Hilbert space operator adjoint is not the same as that of the dual spaces (adjoint) operator.

Comment: Interesting - could you elaborate on that?

Comment: The Hilbert space  adjoint (usual -eg matrix conjugate transpose ) of (a blo) $T:H\rightarrow K$ is a (blo) $T^*$ such that $\langle Tx,y\rangle=\langle x,T^*y\rangle$. On the other hand, we have dual spaces of $H,K$, denoted say by $H',K'$ (dual space of $H$- where $H$ is a normed space- is the set of all bounded linear functionals on $H$ equiped with the functional norm). Every $T$ as above has also an unique associated adjoint $T':Y'\rightarrow X'. The two concepts are different.